# nginx docker port mapping - access original port

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I am setting up docker setup with a reverse proxy. Depending on the filename, some requests are forwarded on to one container and some to the other. I need to also pass the original port.
The initial request comes in port for example 8091, and forwarded on to 80. How do I pass the port? I've tried $server_port and $remote_port, both didn't do what I wanted.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

The reason for running under multiple ports is to support multiple application deployments under the same server. So the multiple apps can be deployed by deploying multiple docker setups mapping via different ports.

Comment: Your question does not seem to have all information IMHO, why you dont set a server block for a specifiy port and forward it for your 8091 with proxy_pass?

Comment: @djdomi updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx will add Forwarded-Port from $server_port, exactly the way you did it.
One thing you should keep in mind though is that all of this magic is happening from Nginx's perspective, and from its perspective $server_port is going to be what was requested of nginx before it forwarded this request to another server.

Imagine this simple setup

```
client --> (8080) docker --> (80) nginx
                                    |- /srv1 --> (8880) srv1
                                    |- /srv2 --> (8880) srv2
```

In this scenario if you pass extra headers as you proxy requests to srv1 and srv2, $server_port is going to be 80, because from nginx's perspective the request came to port 80 before it was proxies to the next server, as it is unaware of anything that happened with the request before that.

Here is a little [lab](https://github.com/jabbson/docker-nginx-reverse-test) I have for this.

Comment: in your example is there a variable to access 8080, suppose this is not passed on to nginx at the first place as that's jus docker port mapping?

Comment: This is correct, the mapping of 8080 to 80 happens before nginx is aware of any of this, so i do not think it is something you can do with the tools out of the box. You may want to look into setting the port and an environment variable from the .env file and then running extra commands (like sed) in the container during the build to set this header from this passed env var, i've updated the github repo to provide an example.

Comment: This gets even more complicated if you use automatic ports. I.e. docker picks the next available port, possibly on a host running multiple docker apps.